# Calculate Mean: different result for masked image vs ROI

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a weird problem where my average gradient magnitude result is different if I use a mask as opposed to creating a new Mat of that small ROI. I'll explain the 2 different ways I do this and 2 different average gradient magnitude results I get. I thought I should get the same average gradient magnitude result?

> Scenario: Image A is my source/original image of a landscape. I want to get the average gradient magnitude in the region A `(10,100), (100,100), (100,150), (10,150)`.

**Technique 1:**
- Create a ROI `Mat` that just shows region A. So its dimensions are `90` by `50`.
- Perform `cv::Sobel()`, `cv::magnitude()` then `cv::meanStdDev()`
- My average gradient magnitude result is `11.34`.

**Technique 2:**
- Create a new `Mat` that is a mask. The mat is the same dimensions as Image A and has a white area where Region A is. Then create a new Mat that just shows that region of Image A and the rest of the Mat is black - hopefully this makes sense.
- Perform `cv::Sobel()`, `cv::magnitude()` (but use the mask) then `cv::meanStdDev()`
- My average gradient magnitude result is `43.76`.

Why the different result?

Below is my code:

```
static Mat backupSrc;
static Mat curSrc;

// Technique 1
void inspectRegion(const Point& strt, const Point& end) {

    curSrc = Mat(backupSrc.size(), CV_8UC3);
    cvtColor(backupSrc, curSrc, CV_GRAY2RGB);

    Rect region = Rect(strt, end);
    Mat regionImg = Mat(curSrc, region);

    // Calculate the average gradient magnitude/strength across the image
    Mat dX, dY, mag;
    Sobel(regionImg, dX, CV_32F, 1, 0);
    Sobel(regionImg, dY, CV_32F, 0, 1);
    magnitude(dX, dY, mag);

    Scalar sMMean, sMStdDev;
    meanStdDev(mag, sMMean, sMStdDev);
    double magnitudeMean = sMMean[0];
    double magnitudeStdDev = sMStdDev[0];

    rectangle(curSrc, region, { 0 }, 1);

    printf("[Gradient Magnitude Mean: %.3f, Gradient Magnitude Std Dev: %.3f]\n", magnitudeMean, magnitudeStdDev);
}

// Technique 2
void inspectRegion(const std::vector<Point>& pnts) {

    curSrc = Mat(backupSrc.size(), CV_8UC3);
    cvtColor(backupSrc, curSrc, CV_GRAY2RGB);

    std::vector<std::vector<Point>> cPnts;
    cPnts.push_back(pnts);

    Mat mask = Mat::zeros(curSrc.rows, curSrc.cols, CV_8UC1);
    fillPoly(mask, cPnts, { 255 });
    Mat regionImg;
    curSrc.copyTo(regionImg, mask);


    // Calculate the average gradient magnitude/strength across the image
    Mat dX, dY, mag;
    Sobel(regionImg, dX, CV_32F, 1, 0);
    Sobel(regionImg, dY, CV_32F, 0, 1);
    magnitude(dX, dY, mag);

    Scalar sMMean, sMStdDev;
    meanStdDev(mag, sMMean, sMStdDev, mask);
    double magnitudeMean = sMMean[0];
    double magnitudeStdDev = sMStdDev[0];

    polylines(curSrc, pnts, true, { 255 }, 3);

    printf("[Gradient Magnitude Mean: %.3f, Gradient Magnitude Std Dev: %.3f]\n", magnitudeMean, magnitudeStdDev);
}
```

Comment: I think your mask should be of type CV_8UC3 i.e. `Mat mask = Mat::zeros(curSrc.rows, curSrc.cols, CV_8UC3);`. May be it is copying only one channel

Answer (score 1):

In technique 2 the gradients around the boarders of your rectangle will be very high and will corrupt the calculation.

Consider dilating your mask before computing the gradients so that this spike is outside of the non-dilated mask that you send into the `meanStdDev` function.

Comment: thanks :) Dilating the mask brings the 2 results slightly closer together but eroding the mast brings them much closer together - technique 2 now gives 11.97. Is there anyway to make this completely accurate (the same as technique 1)?

Comment: To be clear you need to dilate the mask before the `copyTo` call. Then you should erode it back to its original size before calling `meanStdDev`. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks :) I will try dilating it before. What I am trying to do is calculate the avg gradient magnitude in a polygon (the polygons outline highway lanes in an aerial image). So in my example above the polygon is a simple rectangle but in reality they are complex polygons. The polygons are achieved by masks, ie, the Mat is the same image as the original aerial image except most of the Mat is black except for inside the polygon.

Comment: So, you want the second method to work. For one thing, there's no reason to zero out the area outside of the mask. Don't make the call of `copyTo`. You're using the mask in `meanStdDev`. That's enough.